# Event ID 3 / Source: Print

Tags: printing, dns, domaincontroller, event-id

I came across an Event error on System.

```
Event ID:3
Source: Print
Description: Printer HP LaserJet on [domainname] (from IT01) in session 2 was deleted.
```

The `IT01` is my PC at work, and I have not done any printing today.

Also there are 6 printers configured on the Print Server, and for each printer I have the same error.

I really have no idea why, and I can't find anything related in a google search.

Hopefully someone here can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you're looking for depends on a couple of things.

If the printer still works when you try again, then the terminal services session that loaded your printer has deleted the link to your printer when the session was terminated.

If the printer does not work, according to here: http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=3&source=print
The printer may have been deleted by something different